# Recommendation to embed Haskell as script engine in iOS apps on ARM?

Tags: ios, haskell, arm, embedding

I tried to compiling Haskell into an iOS app a few months ago.
Unfortunately the only **stable/maintained** implementation that I could find was GHC, so I tried some kind of cross-compilation, but failed because of absence of RTS for ARM/iOS.

I realized it's not easy enough for me. So I'm requesting some recommendations for this. I know there's a patch for iOS, but it's not continued anymore. I considered NHC/YHC, but I couldn't use dropped implementation. If I'm thinking wrong, please correct me.

Comment: If you are looking for a scripting language you might want to consider lua.

Comment: Try [Hugs](http://www.haskell.org/hugs/).

Comment: @Femi I'm currently using Lua :) But I'm wishing to switch to Haskell.

Comment: Ah. Alright. Good luck. I'll follow this: will be interesting to see what you come up with.

Comment: @n.m Hugs looks abandoned. And I cannot bear the risk of choosing  discontinued implementation :( As I know it's features integrated into GHCi.

Comment: I'd look around before saying it's abandoned... I think a lot of the Haskell libraries are written so that they work with ghc, hugs, nhc, etc. Besides, sometimes great tools live longer than their latest revision ... you wouldn't exactly say that `bash`, `ls`, and `awk` are abandoned, right?

Comment: If you need Haskell 98, Hugs is already an excellent, portable, lightweight, stable implementation and it doesn't matter if it continues to be updated or not. If you need cutting edge, then Hugs is obviously not it.

Comment: @gatoatigrado, @n.m Hmm. Your comments are very persuasive. If it's stable enough, it should be fine to use. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Eonil Please post back if you have any successes, thanks :)

Comment: GHC's LLVM back-end has great potential. Too bad it isn't quite mature enough.

Answer (score 8):

This is fairly easy using [GHC-iPhone](http://projects.haskell.org/ghc-iphone/downloads/GHC-iPhone.pdf) and the  [Foreign Function Interface](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foreign_Function_Interface)

For reference, David Pollak has an example implementing a Lisp interpreter written in Haskell, running inside an iPad app:

> https://github.com/dpp/LispHaskellIPad

An example declaring the Haskell main in `main.m`:

```
extern int Haskell_main(int argc, char* argv[]);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Haskell_main(argc, argv);
}
```

and in his `Main.hs`, a series of foreign function declarations granting him access to the Cocoa libs:

```
foreign import ccall safe "openWindow" openWindow
         :: IO CInt

data ViewController_struct
type ViewController = Ptr ViewController_struct


type RunStr = ViewController -> CString -> IO ()
foreign import ccall safe "wrapper" wrapFuncInvoke :: RunStr -> IO (FunPtr RunStr)
foreign import ccall safe "setLispEval" setLispEval :: ViewController -> FunPtr RunStr -> IO ()

foreign import ccall safe "addToResult" addToResult :: ViewController -> CString -> IO ()

data ObjCId_struct
type ObjCId = Ptr ObjCId_struct

data ObjCSEL_struct
type ObjCSEL = Ptr ObjCSEL_struct

foreign import ccall safe "objc_msgSend" objc_msgSend :: ObjCId -> ObjCSEL -> IO ObjCId
foreign import ccall safe "objc_msgSend" objc_msgSendInt :: ObjCId -> ObjCSEL -> Int -> IO ObjCId
foreign import ccall safe "sel_registerName" sel_registerName :: CString -> IO ObjCSEL
foreign import ccall safe "objc_lookUpClass" objc_lookUpClass :: CString -> IO ObjCId
```

Comment: Heh... I found this post when I was searching for some GHC-iPhone stuff... feeling recursive. ;-)